# Installing a library in Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, installation

I am looking for the step by step process for installing a new library. I am new to Eclipse and real development work (I only roughly know what a 'bin' and 'lib' are for).

There are similar questions but none have a step by step walkthrough. Thanks for your time!

Some details if it helps your example:

- I am using Eclipse 3.6.2 on Mac OS X.
- I am using PyDev for python.
- I am trying to add PyDelicious.
  http://code.google.com/p/pydelicious/downloads/list

Comment: You're trying to install a Python module. It has nothing to do with Eclipse. Unzip that downloaded file, `cd` into the directory via Terminal, and run `sudo python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should need to do is

```
easy_install pydelicious
```

in [Terminal.app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal.app). It says so [right on the project home page](http://code.google.com/p/pydelicious/).